# How to correctly read an integer?

Tags: c, fgets, getchar

My program to test if a number is power of two works for positive integers well. But when I enter a real number like 5.4, the line `c=getchar()` does not wait for my input.

```
int main() {
        int num;
        char c = 'y';
        printf("\n\n");
        do{ 
            printf("**********************************************\n");
            printf("Enter a positive integer to test: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            getchar();
            if(num<0) {
                printf("cannot accept a negative integer.\n");
            }   
            else
                is_power_of_two(num);
            printf("Do you want to try again?\nEnter 'y' if yes, else press any other key to exit: ");
            c = getchar();
            printf("**********************************************\n");
        }while(c=='y');
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter a positive number to test: 8
Yes it is a power of 2
Do you want to try again?
Enter 'y' if yes, else press any other key to exit: y
**********************************************
**********************************************
Enter a positive number to test: 7.6
No it is not a power of 2
Do you want to try again?
Enter 'y' if yes, else press any other key to exit: **********************************************
```

I have tried using fgets and atoi instead of scanf and getchar() like the following. But then fgets doesn't wait during the second iteration. I tried clearing numbuff in every iteration. But no difference. Does getchar() also leaves \n in the buffer like scanf?

What's happening here and is there a simple way or correct way of reading an integer without causing a lot of trouble?

```
int main() {
    char numbuf[10];
    int num;
    char c = 'y';
    printf("\n\n");
    do{ 
        printf("**********************************************\n");
        printf("Enter a positive number to test: ");
        fgets(numbuf, sizeof(numbuf),stdin);
        num = atoi(numbuf);
        if(num<0) {
            printf("cannot accept a negative integer.\n");
        }   
        else
            is_power_of_two(num);
        printf("Do you want to try again?\nEnter 'y' if yes, else press any other key to exit: ");
        c = getchar();
        printf("**********************************************\n");
    }while(c=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
**********************************************
Enter a positive number to test: 9
No it is not a power of 2
Do you want to try again?
Enter 'y' if yes, else press any other key to exit: y
**********************************************
**********************************************
Enter a positive number to test: No it is not a power of 2
Do you want to try again?
Enter 'y' if yes, else press any other key to exit:
```

Comment: Do you *want* to be able to input floating point numbers? Then the `scanf` format you use to read *integers* is not going to work. If stepped through the code in a debugger you would have seen that the `getchar` call to discard the newline would return the `'.'` and the next `getchar` would return the first decimal. If you don't want to read a floating point value, then using `fgets` and then use `strtol` to attempt to convert the input to an integer.

Comment: `getchar` means to get the next character from the input stream, not necesssarily to wait for input. If there is already a character in the stream it won't wait. In this case `.`

Comment: At the `fgets` solution just add `getchar();` after `c = getchar();` to consume `'\n'` char before new call to `fgets`.

Comment: @LPs But in that case, it takes two enter keys to exit the program if I want to exit it just by pressing a single enter key.

Comment: No. You enter y and enter. Without the second `getchar` you consume newline char with `fgets`, with the second `getchar` you consume immediately the newline and the while will continue/close based on the user answer. BTW you have many other problems with your code, e.g: what happen if the user type `yes` instead of `y`?

Comment: @LPs I understand why you have suggested to use getchar(). What I am saying is that when I want to send '\n' for the sake of exiting, I have to give '\n' twice to exit, one '\n' for `c=getchar` and other '\n' for `getchar();`.

Thanks for pointing out the other problem.

Comment: No. `c=getchar()` will get `'y'` the second one `'\n'`...

Comment: @LPs 'y' is for yes. I am talking about exiting. I can press '\n' directly for exiting. In this case it requires pressing '\n' twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged your code and see an interesting thing in it: when you enter a floating number such as 5.4, 5 is saved in num and 4 remains, so when it is asked to enter a 'y' or press any key, '4' is scanned, and the program terminates.
see the picture(i have entered 5.4)
[image: here is the locals]

i think if you define num as type of float, your problem gets solved.

Comment: Defining num as float gives me strange values for num if I try to do `printf("%d\n",num);` or `printf("%f\n",num);`

Comment: @vikramreddym this does'nt happen for me. maybe there is problem in other parts of your code. but if you do not want to print the flaoting point, you can use         printf("%.0f\n", num);

Comment: If you declare `num` as `float` you must change `scanf` format specifier to `%f`...

Comment: I have accepted this answer. But additional condition is required to check if the input number is an integer.